# "Return values" of univariate logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, calibration

I read an interesting article on an approach to calibrate probabilistic classifiers ([Kull et al. 2017, "Beyond sigmoids: How to obtain well-calibrated probabilities from binary classifiers with beta calibration"](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ejs/1513306867)) and stumbled across a formulation that is unclear to me.

In the second step of algorithm 1 the authors write

$$(a,c) \leftarrow \mathrm{fit\: univariate\: logistic \:regression \: to \: predict \: y_{train}\: from\: \mathbf{s}'}$$

which left me confused. In my understanding this assigns the "return values" of the logistic regression fit to the variables $a$ and $c$.
While the authors state that this approach to acquire these two parameters for their function makes it possible to use any implementation of logistic regression, these usually only either return a model object or the coefficients of the model (which should amount to the same).

On page 8, section 3.1, the authors introduce the parameters $a,b,c$ and in proposition 1 they show that the likelihood ratio of the logistic model is equal to that of their parameterization of the used beta distribution, which is supposed to show that fitting a logistic model to acquire the parameters is sufficient - however they don't seem to write a word about the formulation above besides

> *Hence, we can use logistic calibration (i.e. univariate logistic
> regression) to fit the beta[a=b] calibration maps, as shown in
> Algorithm 1.*

Maybe this is just too trivial for the authors to write more explicitly, can someone explain to me what exactly the authors assign to $a$ and $c$ here?

Edit: for completeness sake, here's a screenshot of algorithm 1 from the paper
[image]

Comment: Did you answer this on your own or you want help? I read the paper but I did not invest the time to write an answer. (I like your questions in general, very thoughtful +1.)

Comment: No i did not answer it, I had to move my attention elsewhere. Id still appreciate an answer, if its not too much to ask ;)

Comment: I have not forgot about this. I just try to reproduce the results from the paper but I do not get the time! (I have seen the repo.)

Comment: No sweat, I don't need this for work anymore, I'm merely curious ;)

Comment: What is the $s'?$

Comment: @Dave I added a picture of the algorithm definition, there it's explained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that [logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression#Definition_of_the_logistic_function) is a model that predicts the odds

$$
\frac{p(x)}{1 - p(x)} = e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 x}
$$

Now look at the *Preposition 1* in the paper (p 5062)

$$
LR_\text{logistic}(\ln \tfrac{s}{1-s};a,c) = \exp[ a\ln\tfrac{s}{1-s}+c ]
$$

It seems like *Algorithm 1* (p 5063) is a "univariate logistic regression" with $y_\text{train}$ being the dependent variable, $s'=\tfrac{s_\text{train}}{1-s_\text{train}}$ being the independent variable, $a$ being the slope and $c$ intercept. In *Algorithm 2*, it is a "bivariate" model with $s'=\ln s_\text{train}$ and $s''=-\ln (1-s_\text{train})$ as features and $a,b$ as parameters.